# What's the difference between "docker start" and "docker restart"?

Tags: docker, containers

As it relates to stopping/starting a container?

After stopping a container:

```
docker stop <container id>
```

It seems like I can run either "start" or "restart" to bring it back up.  I'm wondering if there is any difference, or if they are functionally equivalent:

```
docker restart <container id>
docker start <container id>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `docker restart` command will issue a stop and then a start. If the container is already stopped, it is functionally the same as `docker start`. The difference is if you are trying to do the operation on a container that may or may not be running, `docker restart` is more robust in this situation.

Comment: @JoelBondurant can you explain us more precisely what you are talking  about please